# Android : setBackground method changes View's height

Tags: java, android, mobile

When I change background color programmatically, it stretches the width of `TextView`.

```
@Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull ViewHolder holder, int position) {
        holder.textCategory.setText(categoryList.get(position).getName());
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
            if (categoryIndex == position) {
                holder.textCategory.setBackground(context.getDrawable(R.drawable.categories_background));
            } else {
                holder.textCategory.setBackground(context.getDrawable(R.drawable.temp_background));
            }
        }
    }
```

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
    android:layout_margin="3dp"
    android:background="@drawable/categories_background"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">
    <TextView
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:fontFamily="sans-serif-light"
        android:textAllCaps="true"
        android:id="@+id/categoryName"
        android:paddingBottom="10dp"
        android:paddingTop="10dp"
        android:paddingRight="10dp"
        android:paddingLeft="10dp"
        android:textColor="#262626"
        android:textSize="16sp"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
</androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>
```

The width of the `TextView` is getting wide whenever I click. But, I want to keep the width the same and only change background color.

This is the unselected statement for GENERAL tab
[image: This is the unselected statement for GENERAL tab]

And this is the selected statement
[image: And this is the selected statement]

Comment: can you show the picture? I can't understand what you mean by "getting wide".

Comment: @PayaKamyar screenshots have been added.

Answer (score 0):

Is there any space or different character in there? Could you check it by debugging? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I also faced this strange issue, for me the height of the control was distorted when changing background color, I used the following workaround when the distortion occurred:

```
        if (backGroundColorChanged) {
            ViewGroup.LayoutParams layoutParams = newBookmark.getLayoutParams();
            Resources r = getResources();
            float px = TypedValue.applyDimension(
                    TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_DIP,
                    25, // if I call setBackgroundColor, the height will be distorted -> set it to 25dp
                    r.getDisplayMetrics()
            );
            layoutParams.height = (int)px;
            newBookmark.setBackgroundColor(myContext.getColor(R.color.green) );
            newBookmark.setLayoutParams(layoutParams);
        }
```